# Polarity protection for mppt solar battery controller

Tags: battery-charging, reverse-polarity, mppt

I have a cheap MPPT solar battery charge controller I use as a lab for high school students. It has no reverse battery polarity protection and wanted to add some protection because we've lost some units already.

My go-to of an inline diode doesn't work obviously because (a) diode voltage drop and (b) current direction based on charge/discharge.

Right now my solution is to use gendered connectors, but those aren't foolproof because the leads can accidentally be reversed when assembling lab units (the gendered connectors +/- can be difficult to see and isn't color coded). I was hoping for something a little more foolproof.

Any ideas?

Comment: My 2 cents/quid is to pre-wire or solder the leads/connectors, so that they can *only* be connected properly. Use color-coded wiring everywhere, so that a mistake is obvious.

Comment: 4P Molexpower plugs may be better,ike HDD on PC's otherwise Dual Fet reverse protection board is needed

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/305425/2028

Comment: Fuseholder and bunch of replacement fuses?

Comment: Add the diode.  Battery doesn't quite charge to 100%, oh well! Does it even matter for a school project?